# Super slow internet requests

Tags: command-line, networking, ethernet

My Internet connection seems to be extremely slow on loading pages, specifically (it appears) when the browser sends the request for the first time. It takes like 5-6 seconds just to send the request and read the response back.

I don't think there are problems with the router, since the problem appeared only after a system reinstall (ArchLinux) and I probably misconfigured something.

How can I indentify the bottleneck here? The problem seems to be appearing only with the browser (Chromium). Also, what's strange is that my Ethernet interface, which was `eth0`, now (after the reinstall) is `enp2s0`. Another thing that is strange is that `localhost` is not reachable (but I set up a server behind it):

> Chromium's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website
>   may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

**but** `localhost:8001` can be reached without any problems.

I suspect the problem is the last Chromium suggested, i.e. a misconfigured network. What can I do to diagnose it?

Here is the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

**EDIT**: The problem seems to be DNS lookup. What do you suggest? Should I look into Google DNS?

Comment: Check your DNS settings and /etc/nsswitch.conf

Comment: Have a look at `tools > developer tools > network`. That shows you what the delay results from.

Comment: @schaiba: Unfortunately I cannot interpret what's inside `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, even with the help of some online resources. I pasted it here anyway: http://pastebin.com/Gr7n78PX

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Thanks, did that. As schaiba suggested it is really probable that the problem is the DNS lookup, as it shows that to load `stackexchange.com` it took `8.35 s`, `8` of which were due to DNS lookup.

Comment: Please paste the contents of /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @schaiba: Ok, here it is: http://pastebin.com/ifeWahk1. I read that I can change the DNS server IP so I'm thinking of switching to Google DNS. The problem is that dhcpcd will override it. What do you suggest? Is write-protecting `/etc/resolv.conf` enough?

Comment: If your router offers DNS, there's no need to change it. Perhaps DNS lookups take lots of time on the router itself, try rebooting it first.

Comment: @schaiba: This is weird: with `dig` command I can see that the query does not take more than 100 ms even using the router DNS...